# HTTP requests freeze for several minutes after a few axios requests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

My Vue app has a dashboard with items where if the user clicks on an item, several things have to be loaded in different tabs in the background, for example: comments, editable fields, metadata, input choices. All of these data need to be queried from the MySQL database.

My problem is that after a few (6) clicks, axios simply stops working for around 4-5 minutes. After 4-5 minutes it finally responds with the data but I can not find out why this happens.

I have tried putting setTimeout on the some of the axios requests that are made simultaneously, but it still becomes unresponsive after 6 working tries.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Edit:

Here is a picture of the requests that happen when I click an item for example:

[image]

After I click different items 6 times it stops working for 4-5 minutes

[image]

The 5th set of requests still works and then when I click an item for the 6th time it just stops working

Here is an example of one of the axios requests that I make:

```
try {
      const rowResponse = await axios.get(`${process.env.SERVER_URL}/get_company_info?company=${company}&directory=${selected_file}`)
      console.log('metadata response:', rowResponse)
      const values = rowResponse.data[0]
      for (let key in values) {
        this.$set(this.input, key, values[key])
      }
      return true
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
      alert(error.message)
    }
```

Edit 2: Here is a picture of the network tab in my DevTools

[image]

Edit 3: Additional picture after another attempt

[image]

Comment: Are your requests being rate-limited?  We can't diagnose the issue without details.

Comment: can you share the axios request? and a screenshot of the network tab in your devtools

Comment: I added some pictures and an example of one of my axios requests

Comment: Oh shoot nevermind, I found the answer to this problem thanks to @Tzelon asking to share a screenshot of the network tab. I noticed that one of the requests was taking way too long and when I commented it out the problem stopped happening. So the problem lies with that particular request in my express server.

Comment: The network tab shows it's waiting for something, before even sending a request to the server, you could try clearing your cache, and closing any other open tabs to the same domain name